# Get loaded variables with $CI->load->vars() in controller with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I know how to load a variable from a controller to make it reachable to all views:

```
$data['xxx'] = 'yyy';
$CI->load->vars($data);
```

It's easy like that.

But how could I pass the `xxx` variable to a child controller instead of a view?

`$data` variable doesn't seem to exist in extended controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Child controller automatically inherits all public and protected variables and methods from parent controller.So you not need to pass separately.Here is a example..

```
class Parent_controller extends CI_Controller
{
  protected $xxx = 'hello im parent';

  public function_name(){

  }

}
```

Then make a child controller extending `Parent_controller` as below:

```
class Child_controller extends Parent_controller{
    echo $xxx; //outputs hello im parent OR you can overright it
     //similarly you can make function call to parent's function
      }
```

Study on the topic about Inheritance will be enough for you.But variables and methods with private scope are not accessible to child controllers.